# How to create a link (ln -s) with an absolute path?

Tags: filenames, ln

So using `ln -s` to make a link will make either a relative link (`link->../file`) or an absolute link (`link->/home/user/dir1/file`).

But sometimes I don't want to type the entire absolute path, but still need an absolute link.  Maybe I want to link `link->../dir2/file` but I really want `link->/home/user/dir/another dir/a third dir/dir6/dir2/long named dir/dir/dir2/file`.  That's a lot of typing.

What's an easier way to do that then this?

```
ln -s "/home/user/dir/another dir/a third dir/dir6/dir2/long named dir/dir/dir2/file" link
```

Thanks, my fingers appreciate it.

Comment: One way to avoid typing too much is to use «tab». It will still be more typing than you are hopping for. But also works in more situations.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I found one way to make it work easily:

```
ln -s `realpath ../dir2/file` link       #not perfect
```

It's not perfect - `$( ... )` is preferred to `` `...` `` for command substitution, and there's a problem with filenames with spaces - the `"double quotes"` fix that while allowing command substitution to proceed.  So here is an updated answer:

```
ln -s "$(realpath ../dir2/file)" link
```

So if I want the filename to be the same,

```
ln -s "$(realpath ../dir2/file)" .
```

Comment: Note: `$(command)` is preferred over back ticks, and see `symlinks` tool.

Comment: Is `symlinks` a windows tool?

Comment: No it is command line.

Comment: Wow, I am not finding any documentation for it anywhere.  Could you provide a link?

Comment: on Debian, install with `apt install sysmlinks`. It says that it was written my “Mark Lord”. Hope that helps. Also see man page https://linux.die.net/man/8/symlinks